# Is there any way we can replay QUIC or HTTP/3 pcap using Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, udp, pcap, quic, http3

Is there any way we can replay the captured QUIC or HTTP/3 pcap from Ubuntu machine(any machine) using any tools.

Looking for the tools which would help to replay the QUIC or HTTP/3 pcap on Ubuntu machine or on any another machine using any tools.

Comment: What do you expect from replaying these data, i.e. what is the use case? Note that simply replaying one side and expecting that the other side will work is wrong, since internal state and key information depend on information from both sides and there are random data involved here.

Comment: What is the goal that you're trying to achieve by replaying the captured packets?

Comment: Just looking for the tools which would help to replay the QUIC pcap like tcpdump.